# How to share Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a macro in VBA for Outlook. I want this macro to be enabled all the time when Outlook is open.

1. How can I make it so Outlook does not have to ask me to allow this macro to run? How do I make it a 'trusted' macro.
2. What is the best way to share this macro with colleagues?

Here is the macro script, the code works fine, I am looking for help on sharing this with other in my office:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
  Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim i
  Dim prompt As String
  Dim checklist As String
  Dim lbadFound  As Boolean
  Dim badAddresses As String
  lbadFound = False

On Error Resume Next
 ' use lower case for the address
 ' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case

 ' checklist contains the names and email addresses of people involved in the Build Option

  checklist = "test@gmail.com" 

 Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
    For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
      Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

      If InStr(1, LCase(checklist), LCase(recip)) >= 1 Then
          lbadFound = True
          badAddresses = badAddresses & recip & vbCrLf
      End If

    Next i

    If lbadFound Then
       prompt$ = "You are sending this email to one or more people on the Build Team: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & badAddresses & vbCrLf & " Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How can I make it so Outlook does not have to ask me to allow this macro to run? How do I make it a 'trusted' macro.

You may adjust the Trust Center settings in Outlook or just sign macros with a digital signature. See [Troubleshooting Outlook VBA](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=68) and [Signing your own macros with SelfCert.exe](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm) for more information.

> 2) What is the best way to share this macro with colleagues?

VBA macros are not designed for distribution. All possible ways are described on the [To distribute Microsoft Outlook VBA code to other users](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28) page.

Instead, I'd suggest developing an add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.